# Bounding the cardinality of the Stone-Cech compactification.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $X$ be an infinite topological space with Stone-Cech compactification $\beta X$. I want to bound the cardinality as a function of the cardinality of $|X|$:
$$|\beta X| \le f(|X|).$$

**Attempt**: We can realise $\beta X$ as the characters of $C_b(X)$, i.e. there is an embedding
$$\beta_X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}^{C_b(X)}$$
and thus
$$|\beta X| \le (2^{\aleph_0})^{|C_b(X)|} \le (2^{\aleph_0})^{|\mathbb{C}^X|} \le (2^{\aleph_0})^{\left((2^{\aleph_0})^{|X|}\right)}= 2^{2^{|X|}}$$

This is of course a bad estimate. How much better can we do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\beta X| \le 2^{2^{|X|}}$ is a sharp bound witnessed e.g. by the discrete space....Yes, it can be a huge space in general.